# I'm not sure what a certain code line does

Tags: python

I was trying to have a program using Python to create a "pyramid" based on a number, n, out of o's and came up with this: ( I would print nn, that would be the lines.)

```
import time

n = 0
while True:
    n += 2 #just another way to show n=n+2
    nn = n, "o" #nn would be an amount of o's, based on what #n was
    time.sleep(1)
    print (nn, str.center(40, " "))
```

Not sure how to make nn the o's and not sure what line 6 does either. Does anyone know the answer to either question? ( I'm not in a class just programming for fun.)

Comment: Line 6 creates a tuple. Maybe you wanted `"o" * n`?

Comment: And after you've corrected that - don't forget to put a *break* in... you've got an infinite loop right now...

Comment: @Matthias I almost provided OP a link to `sleep`s docs because I started counting from 0. Oh well..

Comment: @Matthias Ya I think that might work thanks!

Comment: It will not work because you have other strange code. What do you think `str.center(40, " ")` does?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy No, I wanted it that way until I figure out how many characters wound fit on my screen.

Comment: @Cman88 fair 'nuff... guess it's how big you make your window :)

Comment: @Matthias yup I know that is for strings I have to use nn.center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [built-in formatting options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) offered by python. Take a look at this:

```
def pyramid_builder(height, symbol='o', padding=' '):
    for n in range(0, height, 2):  # wonkiness-correction by @mhawke
        print('{0:{1}^{2}}'.format(symbol*n, padding, height * 2))

pyramid_builder(20, 'o')
```

The `^` symbol says that you want your print **centered**. Before it (`{1}`) comes the padding symbol and after it (`{2}`) the total width.

This is fully customisable and fun to play with.

Comment: You need to increment `n` by 2 on each iteration otherwise you'll get a wonky pyramid. e.g. `for n in range(2, height, 2):`, or if you want to start with a single `o` at the tip `for n in range(1, height, 2):`

Comment: Thanks that also looks like it would work. I haven't heard about that before.

Comment: @Cman88 by passing different arguments to the function when you call it. If it helps you understand, you can write `pyramid_builder(height=20, symbol='o', padding=' ')` instead of the last line of code above and start tweaking the values to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

n = 0
while True:
    n += 2 #just another way to show n=n+2
    nn = "o" * n #nn would be an amount of o's, based on what #n was
    time.sleep(1)
    print (nn.center(40," "))
```

As someone has mentioned in the comments "o" * n will give a a string containing n "o"s.
I've fixed the print line to use the correct method a calling the center method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

for n in range(0, 40, 2):
    nn = n * "o" #nn would be an amount of o's, based on what #n was
    time.sleep(1)
    print(nn.center(40, " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be the answer to your question

```
import time

n = 0
while True:
    n += 2
    nn = n * "o"
    time.sleep(1)
    print (nn.center(40, " "))
    if n > 30:
        break
```

The reason why they have put `time.sleep(1)` is to make it look like an animation. `print (nn, str.center(40, " "))` this must be changed to `nn.center(40, " ")` as `.center` is a method of string.

Comment: Yes, lol I just realized that str.center would b 4 strings. Thanks